# AttributeError: module 'clr_loader' has no attribute 'wrappers'

Tags: python, clr, python.net, beeware

I am trying use Beeware to package my python prjocet, but when I am trying to use "briefcase dev" command, It raise this error. I found that it need to use pythonnet and clr, and when it call "from pythonnet import load", and raised error when running this line, "_LOADER_ASSEMBLY: Optional[clr_loader.wrappers.Assembly] = None". Because clr_loader do not have wrappers, and I also can't find the discription of clr.wrapper.
What's wrong with these modules? All of them are in the newest version(clr_loader =0.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a clean venv with python 3.10 about an hour ago and ran into the exact same issue.

Upgrading pythonnet to pre-release version 3.0.0rc5 (version 3.0.0rc6 was just released 2 days ago but I did not try that) fixed this issue for my environment.  I originally installed version 3.0.0rc2 which installed clr_loader 0.2.3.